# CSS menu with fly outs

Tags: css, menu

I'm trying to create a very basic page of weblinks, arranged into 7 columns.  Some of the links have sub-links.  What I want to happen is when the mouse is held over a link that has sub-links, the sub-links are to appear just below it and just to the right (as shown in menu 2.2)

I've cobbled the code together from various websites (I'm not a coder!), and I'm almost there I think, but if you take a look at the jsfiddle you will see there is a problem with the 3rd column (I've cut the menu down in the example).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
<ul id="menu">
    <li><h3>Menu 1</h3></li>
    <li><a href="#">1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><h3>Menu 2</h3></li>
    <li><a href="#">2.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2.2</a>
        <ul id="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">2.2.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2.2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>   
</ul>
<ul id="menu">
    <li><h3>Menu 3</h3></li>
    <li><a href="#">3.1</a>
        <ul id="sub2">
            <li><a href="#">3.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3.1.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">3.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3.3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
a {
    font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    display:block;
    padding-top: 17px;     
    padding-bottom: 17px; 
    outline: 0;
}

a:visited {
    color:black;
    background-color:#fff;
}

a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#302403;
    display:block;
}

ul {
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 400px;
}

ul#sub1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#sub2 {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: -15px;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li:hover #sub1  {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu li:hover #sub2  {
    visibility: visible;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 2px solid;
    padding: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/87u27aw0/

I can get it to work if I give each sub-menu it's own absolute position, but I'm sure there is a better way than how I'm doing it - using relative maybe?  Oh, and it has to work in IE8 onwards.

Thanks in advance.

Graybags

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/87u27aw0/1/

Comment: Wow, that was quick!  :)  No, almost, but I'd like the 3.2 and 3.3 to stay where they are, not move down.

Comment: You have to use `position:absolute`  and there is no `float:center`

Comment: I think the float:center was left over from some other stuff, but thanks I will remove it.  If I have to use position:absolute and I have lots of sub-links, that will mean I have to add a different #ul sub for every one?  I thought there would be a more simple way.

Comment: With position absolute [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87u27aw0/2/)